# Python functions don't behave as expected when called from threaded class

Tags: python, python-2.7, thread-safety, minecraft, python-multithreading

I am trying to write a game using the new Minecraft Pi Edition API for Python 2.7. I had the game almost finished, when I realised that there where two sections of the code blocking each other. If I put section A first, it would prevent section B from running, until section A was finished. If I put section B first, it would run really slowly. I decided that I needed to split the two sections into two separate threads. '

This is a cut down version of the code that still exhibits the problem. I noticed that if I commented out the `ClassName.start()` line for one of the two classes, the other class would run without error.

```
import mcpi.minecraft as minecraft
import threading

mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()

class BlockCheckThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            event = mc.events.pollBlockHits()

class WinningCheckThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            blockTest = mc.getBlock(1, 1, 1,) == 50

def main():
    WinningCheckThread().start() # If I comment out either of these .start() lines
    BlockCheckThread().start()   # the other class executes perfectly.
```

The errors from running this were as follows:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
...
TypeError: Hit() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)

Exception in thread Thread-1:
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '
```

To run the code you will need a Raspberry Pi, and will need to download Minecraft from [here](http://pi.minecraft.net/) You then have to run it from the `api/python/` directory. (i.e. It has to be in the same folder as the `mcpi` module it's importing.)

This is my first attempt at threading, so don't laugh too hard at my code. I am interested to know why this code doesn't work, and what I should do to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sharing the `Minecraft` object and it's not thread safe.
The `Minecraft` object is simply a client library to connect to the Minecraft server started with the command `minecraft-pi`. You need to create a `Minecraft` object for every thread and it should be fine:

```
import mcpi.minecraft as minecraft
import threading

class BlockCheckThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()
        while True:
            event = mc.events.pollBlockHits()

class WinningCheckThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()
        while True:
            blockTest = mc.getBlock(1, 1, 1,) == 50

def main():
    WinningCheckThread().start() 
    BlockCheckThread().start()
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! Everything's working perfectly now! Yay! Too many exclamation marks!

Answer (score 3):

The Python Minecraft client of the Pi Edition is not thread-safe. What happens is that the two threads both send and receive data at the same time. When the response get mixed up (i.e. the `BlockCheckThread` gets the response to the request of `WinningCheckThread` and vice versa), the message formats do not match what the threads expect to get.

You can simply put a [lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) around each invocation of the Minecraft client to make sure you send and receive only one item at a time.

I don't know if the Minecraft server supports it, but you may also be able to [send multiple requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipelining). For that, you'll need a manager class that keeps track of the order of the outstanding requests though.